# Referencing a field in a Fabrication

Tags: ruby, rspec, fabrication-gem

In the below example I would like `abbr` to just be the first 3 letters of `name` but I get a >> undefined local variable `name`... I guess because `name` goes out of scope in the {} block?

```
Fabricator(:team) do
  name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  abbr { Faker::Name.first_name[0..2] }
  league { Fabricate(:league) }  
end
```

How can I make `abbr` just the first three letters of `name`?

i.e. this throws the error

```
Fabricator(:team) do
  name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  abbr { name[0..2] }  \\ error name is undefined here
  league { Fabricate(:league) }  
end
```

Comment: Just show the output of `Team.column_names` from your rails console. Just to make sure if you have the `name` attribute in your `Team` model.

Comment: Or show the full error stack

Comment: Your edit makes sense now,

Comment: Try `abbr { Fabricate.attributes_for(:team)[:name][0..2] }` and let me know if it works for you..

Comment: Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also do it by accepting the attributes hash in the abbr value block.

```
Fabricator(:team) do
  name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  abbr { |attrs| attrs[:name][0..2] }
  league
end
```

Unrelated, but league will automatically expand to what you had specified above if you write it like this.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do a before_save callback...

```
Fabricator(:team) do
  before_save {|team| team.abbr ||= team.name[0..2] }
  name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  league { Fabricate(:league) }  
end
```

Edited to make optional if value for abbr is passed.

Comment: Does this prevent me however from passing an "abbr" when I am fabricating though?

Comment: This will no matter what set team.abbr ... if I have passed a value in for "abbr" it will get overridden at save?

Comment: Yes it will override a passed variable but you can fix that with `team.abbr ||= team.name[0..2]`